# batch file to delete all files from the folder which are 3 days older

Tags: batch-file, command

i am using the following command all is fine it deleted the files from the folder i just want to add another condition that the files which are 3 or more days older  gets only deleted

pushd "C:\Bhaskar_Backup\Mail_BOX" && (rmdir . /s /q & popd )

Answer (score 0):

```
forfiles -p  "C:\Bhaskar_Backup\Mail_BOX" -s -m *.* -d 3 -c "cmd /c del @path"
```

Comment: DONT CHANGE MY COMMAND I WANT TO USE THE SAME COMMAND AS THERE IS ALSO A CHECKING IN MY COMMAND THAT IF THE PATH EXIT THEN ONLY THE RIGHT SID EOF THE && WILL BE EXECUTED